# How to fix an encoding error reading an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, psycopg2

I'm trying to make myself a script that will upload an excel file to a postgre db. The source file must be xlsx (it can't be a csv). My script does the job with most files, but one ... that has a column with text (long sentences). For this file in particular I'm getting this error:

```
     26     """
     27 
---> 28     cursor.copy_expert(sql=sql_statement % tbl_name, file=my_file)
     29     print('file copied to db')
     30 

QueryCanceled: COPY from stdin failed: error in .read() call: UnicodeDecodeError 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 6918: character maps to <undefined>
CONTEXT:  COPY clean_file, line 1
```

From what i searched usually this error is due to encoding, thus i did try a bunch of encoding types like utf-8, latin1, cp850, cp1252 .. but none works.
Instead of me keep trying to find the right encoding, i thought it would be easier to actually identify the "trouble" character and just replace it in the excel file (with replace)...
How can i find this character?
"... in position 6918..." is to vague. Is there a way for me to find it?
My library of choice for uploading is psycopg2 (i have to ul to a postgre db). The script works fine without the column in question... so it is obvious something inside one of the cells, is causing this issue

Comment: can you share the entire error log ?

Comment: I just found the solution, after 3 days of googling ...lol. All i had to do is to also add an encoding in the open statement:  my_file = open(file, encoding='utf8'). I had it only in the pd.read_excel statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the error by adding encoding='utf8' in the open statement along with the pd.read_excel statement
df[file] = pd.read_excel(data_path + file, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
my_file = open(file, encoding='utf8')

Comment: nice one, you really made a lot of effort

Answer (score 0):

I experience this issue recently while trying to read a `.xlsx` file

My Solution:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

then read the file as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, index_col=None, engine='openpyxl')
```

I'm glad to help.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solved the issue. It did something though, as the position of the "error" changed... now i have: "charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 7964: character maps to <undefined>"